# Select Feature Based on Iterate Row Value in ModelBuilder

Tags: modelbuilder, fields-attributes, arcgis-10.4, select-by-attribute, iteration

I have a table showing commuting trips from home to work. `home_id` represents home and `work_id` represents work. Now I want to step through the trips table using *Iterate Row Selection* in ModelBuilder, and get the `work_id` value. Then use the `work_id` value to select the corresponding feature in the work location feature class at each iteration.

I used *Get Field Value* tool in ModelBuilder to get the `work_id` value. But how can I pass the `work_id` value to the *Select Layer by Attribute* tool to use in the SQL expression?

I want something like `work_location_id = %work_id%`, but this one gives the "ERROR 00358: Invalid expression" error. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Try adding a sql variable (or called expression, cant remember) then pass Get Field Value to this and then use the expression as input to Select Layer...

Comment: @BERA Thank you. How to do that exactly?

Comment: Is `%work_id%` a number or a string? You don't say. If a string then enclose in quotes.

Comment: @Hornbydd It's a string, and yes, I forgot that. Thank you!